# How long should I let caulking dry before exposing to water?

Tags: plumbing, caulking

I am redoing my bathroom and going from a tub with shower to just a shower base and walls. The walls are fiberglass and caulking is being used to seal everything up. How long should I let everything dry before using this shower?

Answer (score 3):

Check the directions of the caulking product you used, but usually 24-48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of caulk you're using. If you've already selected and purchased the caulk, check the directions on the tube. If you're still in the process of deciding what you want to use, there are a few different factors such as type, full cure time, and "shower ready" time.

GE makes a version of its Silicone II caulk that is ["30 minute shower ready."](http://www.caulkyourhome.com/ge-silicone-II-kb-supreme.php) This means that it isn't fully cured, but it can get wet without any ill effects. Just don't touch it, wipe it, or spray it directly with a high pressure shower head, since it takes a whole 24 hours to cure completely.

They also make a ["3 hour shower ready"](http://www.caulkyourhome.com/ge-silicone-II-kitchen-and-bath.php) version which should give you a bit more time to apply and smooth if you're new to caulking.

(I have no affiliation with GE, I just think they make good products. They're my go-to brand when I need to caulk something.)